# Converting a .binary file into an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, kinect

I have a .binary file that contains Depth data from a kinect sensor.

I am trying to go through the .binary file and get back the actual image in MATLAB. So this is the MATLAB program that I came up with:

```
fid = fopen('E:\KinectData\March7Pics\Depth\Depth_Raw_0.binary');
col = 512; %// Change if the dimensions are not proper
row = 424;
frames = {}; %// Empty cell array - Put frames in here
numFrames = 0; %// Let's record the number of frames too
while (true) %// Until we reach the end of the file:
    B = fread(fid, [col row],'ushort=>ushort'); %// Read in one frame at a   time

if (isempty(B)) %// If there are no more frames, get out
    break;
end


 frames{end+1} = B.'; %// Transpose to make row major and place in cell array
numFrames = numFrames + 1; %// Count frame
  imwrite(frames{numFrames},sprintf('Depth_%03d.png',numFrames));
end

%// Close the file    
fclose(fid);
frm = frames{1};
imagesc(frm)
colormap(gray)
```

The above program works fine but it would not give me any image thats above 99.
That is, I would be processing the .binary file and the last image I obtained is Depth_099.png even though the full video has more than that.

Does anyone knows y?
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just use %04d if you need more digits? %03d is limiting the file name to 3 digits and padding 0.

Comment: Is this code contained within a larger `while` loop, one that iterates over the frame number? Could you post the entire code if so?

Comment: Yes I have tried that but unfortunately increasing the precision does not work. And no it is not inside a while loop.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you're not getting the images above 99 is because of the way you are format specifying your integer as you are creating your file name string as you read in the file.  Specifically, here:

```
imwrite(frames{numFrames},sprintf('Depth_%03d.png',numFrames));
```

`%03d.png` means that you are only specifying up to **3** digits of precision, and so `999` is the max you will get.  If you surpass `999`, then your characters for your file name will also expand in size, so `Depth_1000.png` or `Depth_124141.png` for example.  The `%03d` in the formatting string ensures that your number has three digits of precision, zero-padding to the left of the number to ensure that you have that many digits.  If you want to maintain the same number of characters for your file name, one fix is to probably increase the number of digits of precision, something like:

```
imwrite(frames{numFrames},sprintf('Depth_%05d.png',numFrames));
```

This way, the length of the string will be longer, and going with your convention, you'll get up to `'Depth_99999.png'`.  If you go beyond this, then your file names will increase in character count accordingly.  If you specify `%05d`, you are guaranteed to have 5 digits of precision, zero-padding those numbers that have less than 5 digits accordingly.

Depending on how many frames your video contains, adjust the number accordingly.

---

However, given your comments below.... it could just be that you only have 99 frames of data :)... but the precision tip that I mentioned above should definitely be useful.

Comment: I admit to being confused here too. Why would 3-digit integers stop at `099`? Shouldn't the `%03d` give you three 3 digits, only padding zeros if necessary? `sprintf('Depth_%03d.png',134)` gives me an output of `Depth_134.png`.

Comment: @eigenchris - Yeah I think the OP meant 999, not 099.  Either way, I think increasing the number of digits of precision should help!

Comment: Ah. That would make more sense. :)

Comment: Hi! @rayryeng Thanks for getting back to me on this. Actually Depth_099.png is not a mistake. I tried changing the precision but it would still not give me anything above 99.

Comment: That defies all precision formatting logic.  Doing `sprintf('Depth_%03d.png', 999);` for example gives `Depth_999.png`.  Display `numFrames` at each iteration.  Is it increasing beyond 99?

Comment: @rayryeng yeah it does not increase beyond 99 could it be with the way I am creating the image?

Comment: @AliP - Does it display 99 once, or does it keep displaying 99 and the loop keeps iterating?  If it displays it once, then there are possibly only 99 frames.

Comment: @rayryeng so I stepped through the code and it just exits the loop at if(empty(B))... So could be that there isnt more data

Comment: @AliP - Uh huh... that's what I thought.  You probably don't have any more data :)

Comment: @AliP - I'm closing your post due to a simple typo.  We can't reproduce your error.